# Start Zabbix at boot on Ubuntu 12.04 precise

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, zabbix

I followed the documentation on installing Zabbix from source and it is working great, except that zabbix_server and zabbix_agentd do not automatically start when the system is booted.

I found that the following entries were made for me

**/etc/services**

```
zabbix-agent    10050/tcp                       # Zabbix Agent
zabbix-agent    10050/udp
zabbix-trapper  10051/tcp                       # Zabbix Trapper
zabbix-trapper  10051/udp
```

When I issue the commands

> zabbix-server
>
> zabbix-agentd

from a shell, both start just fine.

What is the correct procedure to ensure that zabbix_server and zabbix_agentd automatically start when the Ubuntu server is booted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following suggestion from the Zabbix forum worked for me:

Copy the init.d scripts to the right spot:

```
sudo cp misc/init.d/debian/zabbix-server /etc/init.d
sudo cp misc/init.d/debian/zabbix-agent /etc/init.d
```

Set the correct permissions and set Zabbix to start when the machine boots:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/zabbix-server
sudo update-rc.d zabbix-server defaults
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/zabbix-agent
sudo update-rc.d zabbix-agent defaults
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want to consider:

When installing from source, the different zabbix components (such as zabbix_server & zabbix_agentd) do take their configuration files from /usr/local/etc instead of /etc/zabbix.

I therefore use symbolic links from /etc/zabbix to /usr/local/etc.

# ln -s /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf /usr/local/etc/zabbix_agentd.conf
 # ln -s /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf /usr/local/etc/zabbix_server.conf

If not, the zabbix components will start on boot, but totally unconfigured.

If I need to start the components from the command line, I need to add the option -c or --config too.

# zabbix_server --config=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
 # zabbix_agentd --config=/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf

Hope this helps.
Jord

Comment: That presumably depends on how the build is configured, OP want might to go over that.